# Count Filtered Results from HTML Table

Tags: javascript, jquery, filter, html-table

I've got a filter that acts upon a table filled with data coming from Mongo. The filter itself isn't connected to Mongo in any way, it basically just sorts through what is displayed in the current view based on matching text. I also have a count of results returned from the database matching the prior search criteria from the previous page. I now want to be able to re-count the results as they are being filtered. This is my JavaScript so far...

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   (function($) {
      $('#filter').keyup(function() {
          var rex = new RegExp($(this).val(), 'i');
          $('tbody.searchable').hide();
          $('tbody.searchable').filter(function() {
            return rex.test($(this).text());
          }).show();
            var x = $('tbody').length;  //'tbody' needs to be changed to the current body display after being filtered
            document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = x;
          })

          $('tbody').on("click", function() {
            if($(this).data('href') !== undefined){
              document.location = $(this).data('href');
            }
         });
       }(jQuery));
     });
```

As of now, the filter will return the total amount of tr's. However, I want to change this to just display what is being shown. Is it possible to do this with just JS and jQuery?

Comment: Are you asking how to do this without jQuery, or with JavaScript in general, including jQuery?

Comment: Ah! Sorry, yes i am including jQuery. I guess when I said solely JS, I mean without having to add any extra plugins, etc. My dev environment is isolated and it's a process to get external resources.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change

```
var x = $('tbody').length;
```

to

```
var x = $('tbody.searchable:visible').length;
```

to only count visible table bodies.

Comment: You could use `tbody.searchable` to be more specific in case there are other tables in the page.